# How to improve Google Vision results while detecting a text on an image if we know the language of

Tags: python, google-vision, text-recognition

How to modify the following Python code to return results in German? Is it possible? Thank you.

```
def detect_text_uri(uri):
    """Detects text in the file located in Google Cloud Storage or on the Web.
    """
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
    image = types.Image()
    image.source.image_uri = uri

    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    print('Texts:')

    for text in texts:
        print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))

        vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])

        print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can specify it using `"languageHints": [ "de"]`

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "imageContext": {
        "languageHints": ["de"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For all types of language codes, check [supported Google vision languages](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages)