# Google vision api OCR not working for Hindi language

Tags: php, google-vision

I am having an issue with detecting Hindi fonts using Google Vision API OCR service. The documentatio says that Hindi is supported.

When I drag and drop an image on their demo page (https://cloud.google.com/vision/), it works flawlessly. However, when I make an API call for the same image, it gives me Korean characters.

I am using their PHP client from github to make the API callls.

I have tested some other foreign languages like Japanese/Chinese. Those seem to be working fine.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Let the google vision know the language upfront. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096942/how-to-improve-google-vision-results-while-detecting-a-text-on-an-image-if-we-kn/49112475#49112475

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve Google Vision results while detecting a text on an image if we know the language of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096942/how-to-improve-google-vision-results-while-detecting-a-text-on-an-image-if-we-kn)

Comment: It is not possible to specify the language upfront. This is clearly some bug because it works on their demo page. Only when I try to use API, it fails. It is ridiculous that they don't have any customer support unless I upgrade my account by paying more. I am already paying for the API access. Only Google can get away with such a terrible customer service.